# Roll back a entire database like I can with transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing some testing on a dev database. I would like a easy way to roll back to a known state, however due to the size of the database restoring from a backup takes 5 minutes to perform.

The work I want to "Rollback" is distributed over many connections, I can not modify the sql for some of the connections because they are from an app I do not have access to the source (so I can't just wrap my connections with a giant `BEGIN TRANSACTION`)

Is there something lighter weight than restoring from a backup but I don't need to explicitly enable like `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and also works to roll back work done by connections that have opened, performed it's work, and closed after the point to rollback to was created?

Comment: Also note that things like CREATE DATABASE are not transaction-able (making up a word there), and therefore un-rollback-able (another made up word).

Comment: Understood, I just need a way to roll back a database, not a entire sql server instance.

Comment: yes, I understand, but what I'm saying is that you can't say `BEGIN TRANSACTION | CREATE DATABASE | ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

Comment: I also can't go (while running queries against database `A`) `CREATE DATABASE B | RESTORE DATABASE A` and expect Database `B` to go away either. I am looking for a lighter weight replacement for restoring a backup, which database snapshots fulfill perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [database snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190467%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) at the beginning and revert to it at the end. You have to however have all connections closed as it is very similar to BACKUP/RESTORE, though it is certainly more lightweight. One way to do it is it kill all the connections before reverting. If your application can reconnect to a database after a connection failure,this should cover what you want to achieve.

```
----To create a snapshot
create database SrcDbSnapshot
on ( name = LogicalFileNameFromSrcDB, 
    filename = 'E:\SrcDB.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF SrcDB
go

----To roll back
--Kills all connections and performs the rollback
ALTER DATABASE [SrcDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [SrcDB] FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'SrcDbSnapshot'
go

----To remove the snapshot
drop database SrcDbSnapshot
go
```

Comment: I am restoring to a clean slate and creating a snapshot now, I will report back on how much faster it is to restore.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! I added a example to your answer for future visitors to be able to see how to use it.